# I am new to vue & just starting with the basics and getting the following error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "./HeaderComponent.vue" from "src\main.js". Does the file exist?

I want to print the message "hello world"

Instead of this, getting error!!

Help!

## App.vue

```
<template>
<header-component />
</template>
<script>
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent.vue'
export default{
name:'App',
components:{
HeaderComponent,
}
};
</script>
```

## HeaderComponent.vue

```
<script >
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent.vue'
export default{
data() {
return{
message:'hello world',    
}
},
components:{
HeaderComponent,
}
};
</script>

<template>
<h1> {{message}} </h1>
</template>
```

## main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import HeaderComponent from "./HeaderComponent.vue";
createApp(App).mount("#app");
export default {
components: {
HeaderComponent,
},
};
```

Please help and guide me.
What i am doing wrong here?:)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows10

Comment: Why does HeaderComponent import itself? Not sure if it contributes to the problem but certainly a  problem itself

Comment: Yes, I agree with @EstusFlask, and you certainly should remove `import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent.vue'` and `components: {
HeaderComponent,
}` from HeaderComponent itself. These lines make no sense.

Comment: I did already still its not working :(